# How to return array of objects by comparing two arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

i have two arrays Here, alreadyAddedAreas is single Array and areasData is a nested Array- Here areasData look like this.Here what i want to return data Like in same structure as Areas Data and add isAdded property if its present in alreadyAddedAreas

```
const areasData=[
  countries: [
    {
      id: 123,
      cities:[
        {
        id: 001,
        areas: [{
          id: 890,
          
        }, {
            id:891
          }]
      },
        {
        id: 002,
        areas: [{
          id: 897,
          
        }, {
            id:899
          }]
      },
      ]
      }
  ]

]
```

//alreadyAddedAreas is an Array of Added Areas

```
const areas: [{
              id: 890,
              
            }, {
                id:891
              }]
```

// Here what i want to return data Like in same structure as Areas Data and add isAdded property if its present in alreadyAddedAreas

```
export const getFilteredAreasList1 = (areasData, alreadyAddedAreas) => {
      const filteredArray = [];
      if (areasData && alreadyAddedAreas) {
        areasData[0]?.cities?.map((city) => {
          return city?.areas?.map((area) => {
            if (
              !alreadyAddedAreas.find((item) => item?.areaID?._id === area?._id)
            ) {
              filteredArray.push({
                ...area,
                isAdded: false,
              });
            } else {
              filteredArray.push({
                ...area,
                isAdded: true,
              });
            }
          });
        });
        return filteredArray;
      }
    };
```

Comment: Not understand what's your problem?

Comment: Your `areasData` is an invalid data structure. It is an array with a key (`areaData = [ countries: []]`)